# Significance of Sharabha avatar defeating Narasimha?

Tags: shiva, vishnu, narasimha, sharabha

What is the spiritual significance of sharabha avatar pacifying Narasimha avatar ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

spiritual significance of narasimha-sharabha battle is to glorify **anyajanma tirtha** & narasimha returning to vishnu form as described in **vamana purANa ch. 36** :

> *28. A holy place **anyajanma falls on the east from saraka**. It is popular throughout the three worlds.*
>
> *29. Attaining the form of a lion and slaying the powerful demon, lord Visnu then dwelling among the animals developed affection for lions.*
>
> *30. All gods including Gandharvas the worshipped lord Siva, saluted him and prayed to him to manage the situation. They explained that the
> return of Nrsimha back in the original form of visnu has become
> necessary.*
>
> *31, 32, 33. Mahadeva disguised himself as Sarabha and fought against Nrsimha for several thousand divine years. **Both gods fell
> into a reservoir while fighting**. Divine hermit **Narada** was in
> meditation on the bank of that reservoir under a pipala tree. He was
> suddenly disturbed and looked at them. **Lord Visnu turned in his
> original form** and Siva in the form of a linga. Narada duly
> worshipped them.*
>
> *35. Salute to god Siva, salute to impressive Visnu. Salute to administrator god Visnu and the god of destruction Siva.*
>
> *36. Salute to Hara of varied forms and Visnu of universal form. Salute to great merciful tyambaka and krsna, the cause of knowledge.*
>
> *37, 38. I am lucky and noble as I could see simultaneously both purusas. **My asrama purified by you has indeed become sacrosanct.
> This place shall gain popularity as anyajanma throughout the three
> worlds.***

**mahAbhArata vanaparva ch.LXXXIII** also has an anecdote to above tirtha:

> To the **east of Saraka**, O chief of the Kurus, there is an
> auspicious tirtha known by the name of **anyajanma**, of the
> high-souled **Narada**. He that bathes there, O Bharata, obtaineth,
> after death, at the command of Narada various unrivalled regions.